# Симуляция передвижения мыши на низком уровне

Tags: c#

Знаю, что есть стандартные WinApi средства для передвижения мыши, но это не подходит к определенной задаче. Возможна ли симуляция на более низком уровне?

Внесу конкретики. Есть некая игра, в которой mouse_event, SetCursorPos никак не воздействуют. Стало быть интересно почему? И есть ли какие-то иные пути достижения цели. Естественно, физический ввод с мышки работает.

Comment: Покажите мне то, не знаю что. Сделайте мне так, не знаю как ...

Comment: На более низком, конечно возможно, напишите драйвер, пусть он представится системе драйвером мыши ...

Comment: А какой эффект вы хотите, что аж его невозможно добиться на WinAPI? Есть подозрение, что если WinAPI этого не смогло, то ничто другое также не сможет.

Comment: @Zoom: Это имеет смысл добавить в вопрос.

Comment: когда-то давно, делал такой фокус через прерывания на асме, но боюсь, что даже если вспомню как имеенно, то этот код мгновенно порежет либо UAC, либо антивирь, т.к. код был из разряда хаков, когда нельзя но очень хочется. В качестве подсказки: ищите в памяти адреса регистров ввода вывода для мыши и работайте с ними напрямую, если система позволит. На шарпе не выйдет, нужен язык с компиляцией в нативный код, прямым доступом к памяти и поддержкой ассемблерных вставок.

Answer (score 1):

вот на ассамблере. сойдет? более низко я не знаю

`

```
    format PE GUI 4.0
    entry start

    include 'win32a.inc'

    ;---------------------------------------------

    section '.code' code readable executable

      start:
        invoke  GetModuleHandle,0
        ;invoke  DialogBoxParam,eax,37,HWND_DESKTOP,DialogProc,0
        invoke  ExitProcess,0

    ;---------------------------------------------

    proc DialogProc hwnddlg,msg,wparam,lparam
        push    ebx esi edi
        cmp [msg],WM_INITDIALOG
        je  .wminitdialog
        cmp [msg],WM_COMMAND
        je  .wmcommand
        cmp [msg],WM_CLOSE
        je  .wmclose
        cmp [msg],WM_TIMER
        je  .wmtimer
        xor eax,eax
        jmp .finish
      .wminitdialog:
        ; ”становить таймер на срабатывание каждую секунду
        invoke  SetTimer,[hwnddlg],1,100,NULL
        jmp .processed
      .wmcommand:
        cmp [wparam],BN_CLICKED shl 16 + IDCANCEL
        je  .wmclose
        jmp .processed
      .wmtimer:
        ; ѕереместить мышку на 1 микки относительно ее текущей позиции
        invoke  mouse_event,MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE,0,0,0,0
        jmp .processed

      .wmclose:
        invoke  EndDialog,[hwnddlg],0
      .processed:
        mov eax,1
      .finish:
        pop edi esi ebx
        ret
    endp

    ;---------------------------------------------

    section '.idata' import data readable writeable

      library kernel32,'KERNEL32.DLL',\
          user32,'USER32.DLL'

      include 'apia\kernel32.inc'
      include 'apia\user32.inc'

    ;---------------------------------------------

    section '.rsrc' resource data readable

      directory RT_DIALOG,dialogs

      resource dialogs,\
           37,LANG_ENGLISH+SUBLANG_DEFAULT,demonstration

      dialog demonstration,'Preventing Windows to Sleeping Demo #1',0,0,190,55,WS_CAPTION+WS_SYSMENU+DS_CENTER+DS_SYSMODAL
        dialogitem 'BUTTON','',-1, 2, -1, 185, 35,WS_VISIBLE+BS_GROUPBOX
        dialogitem 'STATIC','No Screensaver, no Sleeping ;)',-1,6,15,177,13,WS_VISIBLE+ES_CENTER
        dialogitem 'BUTTON','Exit',IDCANCEL,135,37,50,15,WS_VISIBLE+WS_TABSTOP+BS_PUSHBUTTON
      enddialog
```

`

Comment: Это такое же WinAPI.